# trying to push some values inside of an empty array when I use the method, but for some reason, the value of the array is overwriting

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push some values inside of an empty array when I use the submitMessage() method, but for some reason, the value of the array is overwriting instead of adding a new element after the last one, I'm not sure what is happening, Am I doing this in a right way?

```js
submitMessage() {
  const personMessage = this.avatarContainerTarget.classList.contains("hidden");
  const array = []; // <--- THIS IS THE ARRAY
  var message = this.messageFieldTarget.value;
  var time = this.messageTimeFieldTarget.value;

  const messageRecieve = `<div class="message message-received is-not remove"><div class="message-container"><div class="message-text"><p>${message}</p></div></div><div class="message-footer"><div class="message-footerItem"><span class="timestamp">${time}</span></div></div></div>`;

  const messageSent = `<div class="message message-sent is-not remove"><div class="message-container"><div class="message-text"><p>${message}</p></div></div><div class="message-footer"><div class="message-footerItem"><span class="timestamp">${time}</span><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><g><path d="M9 20c-.264 0-.52-.104-.707-.293l-4.785-4.785c-.39-.39-.39-1.023 0-1.414s1.023-.39 1.414 0l3.946 3.945L18.075 4.41c.32-.45.94-.558 1.395-.24.45.318.56.942.24 1.394L9.817 19.577c-.17.24-.438.395-.732.42-.028.002-.057.003-.085.003z"></path></g></svg></div></div></div>`;

  if (personMessage === true) {
    array.push(messageSent); //<-- THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PUSH ONE VALUE
    this.twitterChatBodyTarget.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", messageSent);
    this.mobileTwitterChatBodyTarget.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "afterbegin",
      messageSent
    );
  } else {
    array.push(messageRecieve); //<-- THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PUSH OTHER VALUE
    this.twitterChatBodyTarget.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", messageRecieve);
    this.mobileTwitterChatBodyTarget.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "afterbegin",
      messageRecieve
    );
  }

  console.log(array); //<--- If I print this the length is just 1
  this.messagesArrayTarget.value = array;
}
```

Comment: "If I print this the length is just 1".  That sounds right.  You create an empty array each time the function runs and push one thing to it.  If you want to keep stuff in that array between runs, you need to move it outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically:

```js
function submitMessage() {
  const array = [];

  //do other things
}
```

so whenever you call the function `submitMessage`, you create a new array `[]`. If you want this data to stay persistent, you need to store it somewhere, and retrieve it back at the start of the function. You do `this.messagesArrayTarget.value = array;` at the end of the function, so you could do something like:

```js
function submitMessage() {
 const array = this.messagesArrayTarget.value ?? [];

 //do other things
}
```

This makes it so that your `array` will be `this.messagesArrayTarget.value` if it exists, if it doesn't, then an empty array.